# Spring boot - Ignore all application.properties when running a unit test?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am using Spring Boot, and have a unit test that I want to ignore ALL `application.properties` values, and only use values from another file, `application-test.properties`

I see in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49667825/26510) that I can use `@TestPropertySource` to point to a test properties file, and I can also use it to override a couple of properties.

I've tried this, but it still seems to load the values from `application.properties` as well.

**Is there a way to completely ignore `application.properties` for a single unit test?**

My intent is to run this test with lots of DEFAULT values. I don't want to have to override them in my `application-test.properties` file, I want spring to use whatever defaults it has, as if the property was never set in `application.properties`

Comment: Does setting spring.config.location work ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711871/load-different-application-yml-in-springboot-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the following in my `application-test.properties` file, and it seemed to ignore the properties from the `application.properties` file - I will update if I find better answers!

```
spring.config.name=test
```

NOTE: I think I found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720161/26510) from the link shared above in the question comments by [@A M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2081730/a-m)